# Multi-Inner Join with two tables

Tags: sql-server

So basically, I'm trying to inner join two tables together but they both consist of two inner joins already per query.

I've tried putting an inner join between the two tables but I'm not sure how to do so.

```sql
Select(Table 1... Inner join (Select...)
INNER JOIN
Select(Table 2... Inner join (Select...)
```

So trying to join these two tables together but as I parentheses the statements it's not allowing me to do so.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Which SQL are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server, ...?

Comment: Do you clarify "it's not allowing me to do so."? What error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query structure should be like this-

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN T2 
        ON T1.COL = T2.COL
)A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM T3 
    INNER JOIN T4 
        ON T3.COL = T4.COL
)B 
ON A.COL = B.COL
```

Comment: Thank You! Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: You are most welcome. Please accept the ans if it really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to do.  It this?

```
select *
from (select a inner join b on a.id = b.idA) ab
inner join (select c inner join d on c.id = d.idC) cd on ab.id = cd.idAB
```

Don't forget, when you works with subselect, give your subselect an alias.